# Problema com registrar jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, caminho-relativo

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET com a estrutura Seguinte:

```
ProjetoWeb (raiz projeto)

Compartilhado (pasta)
|---Scripts (pasta)
    |----jquery-1.8.0.js

Masters (pasta)
|----Site.master

Cadastros (pasta)
|----ListarCadastros.ASPX

Relatorio (pasta)
|----Vendas (pasta)
     |----Vendas.ASPX
```

eu tenho registrado na Master page o script:

```
<script src="../Compartilhado/Scripts/jquery.responsivetable.min.js"></script>
```

Para todas as páginas que só tem um nível de pasta, funciona normalmente (ex: a pagina ListarCadastros.ASPX)

mas as páginas com mais níveis(ex: Vendas.ASPX), não finciona.

Já alterei para:

```
<script src="../../Compartilhado/Scripts/jquery.responsivetable.min.js">
```

Mas ai as outras paginas deixaram de funcionar.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma, se me recordo bem pra usar `C#` em ASPX é assim que declara:

```
<script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Compartilhado/Scripts/jquery.responsivetable.min.js") %>">
```

Usando a função ResolveClientUrl ele sempre retorna a URL relativa.